# cmd batch file command is not executed with windows path

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following content in a batch file.

The following command executes fine on a `cmd prompt` but fails when executed as a batch file.

Command : `net use Z: "\\xyz\folder_name" "password" /user:domain\username`

Escaped the backslash with an additional `\`

Bat file content :

```
set MyPath=\\\\xyz\\folder_name
net use Z: "%MyPath%" "password" /user:domain\\username
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That looks fine to me, except you don't need to double all the backslashes.  That's only needed for wmi queries or similar.  Additionally, if you're doing `set MyPath` and the share name has special characters (% or & or similar), you need to quote `set "mypath=\\server\share"`.  Finally, if you've got both `set` and `net use` within a parenthetical code block (a `for` loop or `if` statement, for example), you need delayed expansion to evaluate `!MyPath!`.

Comment: This is exactly the path net use Z: "\\xyz\folder_name" "password" /user:domain\username , there are no special characters ...... I tried double quotes for set mypath as well ......did not work .........

Comment: If `xyz` is the SERVERNAME and `folder_name` is a directory, then it appears that the SHARENAME is omitted. How about `SET MYPATH=\\XYZ\C$\folder_name`?